# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ../modules/org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar

Tags: jpa, weblogic, jdeveloper

I am building a project in jdeveloper 11.1.2, but when i want to deploy it in weblogic it appears the next message

Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ../modules/org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar

The file is there so i don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this problem is removing the hash area named "RunConfigurations" in the project file. (Model.jpr)

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue in different way.
First of all it was an integrated weblogic server and the error was coming exactly after security patches have been installed on my Windows XP machine.

To repair:

In JDeverloper go to "View"->"Application Server Navigotor"; select *IntegratedWeblogicServer* and open properties. We need *Domain Directory*. *Domain Directory* for the `IntegratedWeblogicServer` is not located under `"..:\Oracle\Middleware"`. By default it was placed (at least on my machine) under `"C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Application Data\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.1.38.60.81\DefaultDomain\"`.

So copy entire *modules* folder from you Fusion Middleware home `"..:\Oracle\Middleware\"` to `"C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Application Data\JDeveloper\system11.1.2.1.38.60.81"`.

Restart integrated weblogic server.

It works for me ...
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for JDeveloper version : 11.1.2.1.0:

Right Click **Model.jpr** -> **Project Properties** -> **Run/Debug/Profile** -> Run Configurations. Select **EclipseLink JPA Client** -> **Edit** -> **Launch Settings** -> **Java Options**  --> 
`-javaagent:D:/JDeveloper/modules/org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar`

**D:/JDeveloper/modules** is the path where my `org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar` file is located. 
So give whatever your `org.eclipse.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-1.jar` path is after `-javaagent:`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with JDeveloper 11g 11.1.2.1.0 (R2) in Windows 7, and I solved it by uninstalling the following automatic updates of windows, it is not a problem of a project or specific application in JDeveloper, because it occurs at trying to run the integrated WebServer.
These are the uninstalled updates:

- KB2647518
- KB2665364
- KB2641653
- KB2639308
- KB2621440